# can't build matplotlib (png package issue)

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, fedora

try to build matplotlib on fedora-18, build fails with

```
...
 png: no  [pkg-config information for 'libpng' could not
                        be found.]
...
                        * The following required packages can not be built:
                        * png
```

What should I do/check to build png package ?

Comment: You can install the binary with `sudo yum install python-matplotlib`

Answer (score 22):

Sounds like you don't have `libpng-devel` installed. This install is not handled by pip, so you'll need to install it yourself.

You should be able to install it via `yum`.

```
sudo yum install libpng-devel
```

You may also need `freetype`. Maybe try `yum-builddep matplotlib`?

Comment: I do have linpng installed. But when I try to install the headers (libpng-dev), yum tells me "No package libpng-dev available." Sounds like the headers are in some other package but what is its name?

Comment: I've found it, it's called libpng-devel

Comment: My mistake, sorry about that. I'm not using Fedora, I'm pretty sure it's named differently in aptitude. Glad you found it.

Answer (score 2):

Under Cent Os 7, I was able to install matplotlib after installing libpng-static. Please try libpng-static as well as libpng-devel.

Answer (score 2):

In mint/kubuntu as of today, it's named: `libpng16-devtools`, so the command to install it would be:

`sudo apt-get install libpng16-devtools`